# Type mismatch reading CSV file when column is blank

Tags: lotusscript

I read a CSV file (below) into a dimensioned data type...my second record has a blank column (right before field containing SponsorName), and this causes a Type Mismatch error to occur immediately following the Input # method...

The file we read will be a customer supplied CSV file...we anticipate files that will sometimes contain columns with no value.....Should we insist that the customer place some value, like a "0" or "none" in a column when there is no real data for that column for that particular record?

Thanks....

Comment: Without code it is impossible to answer this question

Answer (score 1):

I've found you can not reliably insist that a customer or vendor always provide data. You may want to check to see if each column has a value. I think Karl-Henry's post here http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/texasswede/entry/classimportcsv?lang=en_us is very valuable for what you are doing, and may resolve your problems.

Cheers,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Line Input #` statement instead of `Input #`. See doc [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_LINE_INPUT_LB_STATEMENT.html).

Then you can write code to parse the values.  The `Split` function will probably be helpful for this. See doc [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_SPLIT.html).